# Can there be a different Eigen vector for a particular Eigen value?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, generalized-eigenvector

Please see the photo.[image]

Here, my answer came $k$
$\begin{bmatrix} 
                   1\\
                 1\\
                   -1
\end{bmatrix}$

But their answer is given :
$k$
$\begin{bmatrix}
                     1\\
                    -1\\
                     1
\end{bmatrix}$
My answer is correct?? Please tell--

THE ACTUAL MATRIX]
[image]

Comment: the answer you get might differ, but only by a multiple to the basis vector.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. If you would like to improve the question, please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4016397/edit) it to include the clarifications in the question body.

Comment: No way we can help you without even knowing what the matrix is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  An eigenvalue can be associated with multiple eigenvectors.

For example:  Let $$A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}.$$

The eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ has all non-zero vectors as eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lambda=1$ we have:
$$(A-I)v=0$$
$$\pmatrix{0&1&1\\-1&-2&-1\\0&0&0}\pmatrix {x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix {0\\0\\0}$$
This gives us two equations:
$$y=-z$$
$$-x-2y-z=0 \implies x=z$$
Therefore we have:
$$\implies v=(x,y,z)=x(1,-1,1)$$
You certainly made a sign mistake somewhere.